# Error Report ORA-00904: :invalid identifier

Tags: oracle

```
CREATE TABLE Tour 
(
    TourID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY, 
    Date DATE NOT NULL, 
    AvailableSeats NUMBER NOT NULL, 
    ActualDeparture TIMESTAMP NOT NULL, 
    ActualArrival TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    RouteCode VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, 
    BusRego VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT fk_tour_route FOREIGN KEY (RouteCode) REFERENCES Route(RouteCode), 
    CONTRAINT fk_tour_bus FOREIGN KEY (BusRego) REFERENCES Bus(BusRego)
);
```

I have an issue with creating this Tour Table. I created another table with the same format and it worked well. I found someone with the same issue but he does not have constraint as FK, therefore, I am unsure about mine.

PS: I am a newbie, studying for school assignment.

Anyone?

> Error starting at line : 37 in command -
> CREATE TABLE Tour (
> TourID NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
> Date DATE NOT NULL,
> AvailableSeats NUMBER NOT NULL,
> ActualDeparture TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
> ActualArrival TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
> RouteCode VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
> BusRego VARCHAR2(255) NOT NULL,
> CONSTRAINT fk_tour_route FOREIGN KEY (RouteCode) REFERENCES Route(RouteCode),
> CONTRAINT fk_tour_bus FOREIGN KEY (BusRego) REFERENCES Bus(BusRego)
> )
>
> Error report -
> ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
> 00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
> *Cause:
> *Action:

This is what the script output is.

Comment: `"%s: invalid identifier"` are you sure you're describing the query exactly as it appears?  Also, "NUMBER" is not a valid mysql type.  Is this mysql or oracle DB?  They're quite different.

Comment: It's possible [this may help](https://www.tekstream.com/resource-center/ora-00904-invalid-identifier/)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/KLL-iVhQ how did you not see this I wonder? https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a42525/apb.htm https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/server.901/a90125/sql_elements9a.htm#:~:text=The%20following%20rules%20apply%20when,as%20long%20as%20128%20bytes.

Comment: `CONTRAINT fk_tour_bus FOREIGN KEY ` - you have mis-spelled the word **`CONSTRAINT`**.